# How to change the font size of the mdbDatatable

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mdbootstrap

I am using the MDBDatatable for my react project but I'm having some problems. First of all, I want to resize the table to make a smaller version but I don't think there's an option other than the small property on the component. Also, I want to use a smaller font for the entries of the table but I can't find the class that I need to set in the CSS.Also if I use the fixed property then the entries overflow the cells... Is it possible with MDB or I need to find another solution?

```
<div>
    <MDBDataTable
      className="OrgTable"
      maxHeight="200px"
      scrollY
      striped
      bordered
      hover
      autoWidth
      btn
      small
      data={this.state.data[0]}
    />
  </div>
```